# RF model loses accuracy when I remove it from Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, random-forest, spacy, tfidfvectorizer

Hoping I'm overlooking something stupid here or maybe I don't understand how this is working...

I have an nlp pipeline that does basically the following:

```
rf_pipeline = Pipeline([
('vect', TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = spacy_tokenizer)),
('fit', RandomForestClassifier())
])
```

I run it:

```
clf = rf_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = clf.predict(X_test)
```

When I optimize I get accuracy in the high 90's with the following:

```
confusion_matrix(y_test, preds)
accuracy_score(y_test, preds)
precision_score(y_test, preds)
```

the TfidfVectorizer is the bottleneck in my computations, so I wanted to break out the pipeline. run the vectorizer, and then do a grid search on the classifier rather than running it on the whole pipeline. Here's how I broke it out:

```
# initialize
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = spacy_tokenizer)
# transform and fit
vect = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
clf = rf_class.fit(vect, y_train)
# predict
clf.predict(tfidf.fit_transform(X_test))
```

When I took a look at the accuracy before I ran a full grid search it had plummeted to just over 50%. When I tried increasing the number of trees the score dropped almost 10%.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible by using one of scikit-learn's included datasets? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Answer (score 3):

For test set, you can't call `fit_transform()`, but just `transform()`, otherwise elements of a tfidf vectors has different meaning.

Try this

```
# predict
clf.predict(tfidf.transform(X_test))
```